# getting a list of all roles and granted privileges in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

how can I get a list of all roles and all the privileges I assigned to them (select, insert, delete... etc) in IBM DB2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue just 2 weeks ago... and in DB2. Simply run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES
```

For more info go here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0005823.html

Comment: The answer is not valid for 'Db2 for iSeries' and not relevant for 'Db2 for Z/os'. The answer is only correct for Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Heres what you need in order to get all roles (DB2 LUW):

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.ROLES;
```